# How can I colour the arrow part of a transparent NSPopover window?

Tags: swift, macos, nspopover

I would like the popup to be transparent except for the arrow and the bottom-most part of it (bottom part is no problem, of course). I have a `NSTableView` in the middle so far.

So in `NSPopover` I added an `NSView` on the top and coloured it:

```
viewTop.wantsLayer = true
viewTop.layer?.backgroundColor = myBackgroundColor
```

But the topmost part is still transparent. This is that little thing on the very top like an arrow or so. I would like to make it the same light yellow colour as the `NSView` I put there. Please refer to my screenshots:

[image: popup view hierarchy]

I need to colour the topmost little thing here:

[image: A yellow popover with a grey arrow]

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible with the system-provided `NSPopover`, I'm afraid. You either have to use another popover view implementation, or you could try your hand  at [reverse engineering `NSPopover` and see if you can use some private APIs to style it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PTCKXTPUeqY). That might work, but naturally, since you would be relying on non-public implementation details, it can break in any future release.